# Tag not found unless searched for

Tags: tags, ctags, letter-case

I have a very weird situation with my tags file not working as expected. My tag file is sorted case-insensitively (starts with `!_TAG_FILE_SORTED\t2\t/foldcase/`), and ignorecase is set.

When I put my cursor over `Word_I_Am_Looking_For` and hit `CTRL-]` I get `E257: cstag: tag not found`. However when I type `:ta /<C-W>` to fill out `:ta /Word_I_Am_Looking_For` it finds my tag no problem.

To diagnose the issue I opened the tag file itself and jumped to the line in question. When I turned on `set list` I saw: `Word_I_Am_Looking_For^I/path/to/word/i/am/looking/for^I/\%123l\%456c/$` which looks right to me.

What is causing vim to miss the tag?